# How to get keras 'ones' with variable shape?

Tags: keras

In my keras computation graph, I need a matrix of all-ones, where the second dimension of the vector may change according to some other variable `n`. **Is there a way to get `K.ones` to accept a variable shape?** I currently have a work-around using `K.ones_like` since I happen to have another variable with the proper shape, but I'm curious if there's a better way.

Example code (how would I get `y` if there was no `x`?):

```python
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K

x = K.variable(np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                         [4, 5, 6]]))
n = K.variable(3, dtype=np.int32)

# This works for my case, but only because I happen to have x
y = K.ones_like(x)
print(K.eval(y))

# Both of the following fail with "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."
y = K.ones(shape=K.stack([K.constant(2, dtype=np.int32), n]))
y = K.ones(shape=(2, n))
print(K.eval(y))
```